# AFrame Reflections from Camera in AR?

Tags: aframe

In AFrame, is it possible to use the camera texture for shaders that use reflections? I'm using a threejs water shader in AFrame without a skybox, however, when I enter AR mode on my phone, the water shader is black. The water looks normal if I have a skybox, however, the skybox covers up the camera texture that's provided in AR mode.

I found an article on the [8th wall for realtime reflections](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/cubemap-aframe) in AFrame, but this seems to be using 8th wall's own proprietary tech stack.